# Is Deirdre Wells referring to God in Limetown?

Tags: limetown

In Season 1 Episode 8 of the Facebook Watch TV series Limetown, Deirdre Wells tells Lia Haddock about what happened when the Old School was burning Oscar Totum to death:

> And then, in the middle of the most traumatic thing I've had the misfortune of experiencing something miraculous happened.... I was transported... taken somewhere... comforted. I don't know for a fact, but I think, finally, **it was him**. I've never felt something like that, in my life, and you were calm. Calmer than you've ever been. I had heard Max drunkenly talking about it once. How pure his gift was.

My question is, who is the “him” that Deirdre is referring to?  Is it The Man They Were All There For, i.e. Lia’s uncle?  Or is it referring to God?

I thought the latter was at least a possibility, because Warren Chambers apparently experienced what the pig experienced in the afterlife for a brief moment, so maybe they were experiencing what Oscar was experiencing in the afterlife.  Yet Lia was imagining her uncle in that moment, so I didn’t know if Lia’s uncle was telepathically providing comfort to the people of Limetown, or if Lia was mentally comparing God to her uncle.